# Best way to use a large array in function

Tags: php, functions

I need to define an array which has more than 15000 values in the wordpress functions file:

```
$validpin = array(110019,111222,112233);
```

I have written only 3 values to explain but the actual array will have more than 15000 values. How should I go about doing, as writing 15000 values is making the functions file very large?

Comment: What are you going to do with the values? Your variable name suggest it's "valid pins", but surely there's a rule you could implement, rather than just listing 15000 values.

Comment: The values are postcodes on which I want to restrict certain payment methods, there's no pattern as such as post codes are random. I would need to list post codes individually, need the bast possible way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a list of numbers, I'd suggest just saving them in a text file, with a number on each line.

```
110019
111222
112233
```

Then when you need the file, read its contents with PHP, and use `preg_split()` to turn it into an array:

```
$file_path     = plugin_dir_path( 'postcodes.txt', __FILE__ ); // Or wherever you've placed it.
$file_contents = file_get_contents( $file_path );
$postcodes     = preg_split( "/\r\n|\n|\r/", $file_contents );

if ( in_array( $postcode, $postcodes ) ) {

}
```

That `preg_split()` method for splitting text based on newlines is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11165332).

Comment: I don't see `explode()` in the code, and there's also the `file()` function for reading the entire file into an array.. Also, how about using a comma-separated list in the file - `1,2,3,4,5` ? And then do `explode( ',', $contents )` ..

Comment: Sorry, I meant `preg_split()`. I wrote the sentence before changing my mind and forgot to go back and edit. But yes, you could use explode with commas, but I felt that separating them with line breaks would be easier to maintain.

Comment: Well, one entry per line does look neater than having many numbers there. :) So, +1.

Comment: I also think the database would love this kind of job, to store many rows and search it :-) Sounds also like a good candidate for a web service, if many sites need this, in that case the data needs only be modified in one place.